# Failed to add current user to Hyper-V administrators group error when installing Visual Studio Community 2013

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, hyper-v

I used to have Visual Studio Express installed on my laptop, which worked well, but when I heard Community 2013 was made available for free I decided to install it. However, after running the install process I got the error:

```
Failed to add current user to Hyper-V administrators group
```

The account I am using is an admin account. When I checked for solutions I found many people indicating I had to Microsoft Management Console and add myself to the group, however this laptop has Windows 8.1 Core, not pro, so I cannot add the snapin. So I am not really sure what to do in this situation. Do I need to reinstall, running it as admin? Or will I get the same error again?

Answer (score 6):

Try `net localgroup "Hyper-V Administrators" <username> /add`

in an elevated command prompt

Comment: Should that group exist already? Is it supposed to be created by the installation? The command above results in `System error 1376 has occurred.    
The specified local group does not exist.`

Comment: @RobertGroves, did you find a solution?

Comment: User groups are both case sensitive as well as localized (depending on system installation). To find the correct spelling and casing, type `net localgroup` for a list of local groups available in the system.

Answer (score 1):

It's case sensitive apparently:

Try net localgroup "Hyper-V Administrators"  /add

Answer (score 1):

For me below steps worked with me

preflight checks can all be individually disabled. For the HyperV check you can use:

```
minishift config set skip-check-hyperv-driver true
```

If you prefer the check to happen, but not fail startup, you can use the warn option instead:

```
minishift config set warn-check-hyperv-driver true
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the right name of Hyper-V Administrators group. The group name may be different in the different locales.

Open the window `Windows+R` `->` `lusrmgr.msc`  in this window you may check all groups in your system
and use command

```
net localgroup "<Hyper-V group name>" <username> /add
```